# Set Modal position programmatically relative to the very top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, modal-dialog, position

I have a modal that I'm using as a menu dropdown.
To make this work I am manually setting the height the modal pops up to be right below the menu.
To do this I add the determined number of pixels, and attach the css property "top" to the modal with the fixed number of pixels.
The problem I have is that it is setting that number from the top of where the user is on the page, not the VERY top of the page.
This is an AngularJS modal, but I use jquery to set the css property, and if there is a css solution with jquery, it should be an applicable solution.

Here is how I am setting the number of pixels from the top:

```
                var el = angular.element(element);
            var thumbnail = el["0"];
            var finalThumbnailContainer = thumbnail.parentElement;
            var inte = 0;
            while(inte != 3){
                finalThumbnailContainer = finalThumbnailContainer.parentElement;
                inte++;
            }
            var innerEl = angular.element(finalThumbnailContainer);
            var top = ModalServices.getHorizontalMenuHeight();
            //110
            innerEl.css('top', top);
```

I'm not especially good with layout/css and don't know what to use to get the modal to appear X pixels from the start of the page, rather than where the user is currently on the page.

I would greatly appreciate some help here.

Thanks,

Here is an image of the html of the modal:

[image]

This first image is an image of the modal appearing when the scroll bar is at the top of the page and the second image is the modal appearing when the scrollbar is down the page a little bit.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by subtracting $(window).scrollTop() from my static distance from the top when the scrollbar is at the top.

```
  var el = angular.element(element);
            var thumbnail = el["0"];
            var finalThumbnailContainer = thumbnail.parentElement;
            var inte = 0;
            while(inte != 3){
                finalThumbnailContainer = finalThumbnailContainer.parentElement;
                inte++;
            }
            var innerEl = angular.element(finalThumbnailContainer);
            var top = ModalServices.getHorizontalMenuHeight();
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
             top = top - scrollTop;
            innerEl.css('top', top);
```

Now the modal drops to the correct position right below the menu no matter where the scrollbar is set to....Behold!

[image]